# How can I clear a input field after entering a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on an application that counts the number of books as well as putting the book numbers from lowest to greatest. I have a user input box and I'm trying to figure out how to clear it after the user puts a book number in. I've tried $('#input').val(' '); However, this doesn't allow me to put in numbers of two digits like "23".

My Code:

```js
// global variables
var array = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
  // on enter submit values
  $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      // grabs user's input
      var $input = $('#input').val();
      // stores in the array and sorts from lowest to highest
      array.push(parseInt($input));
      array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b
      });
      // displays user's inputs
      $('#output').text(array.join(", "));
    }
    // to prevent refresh on enter for forms
    $(function() {
      $("form").submit(function() {
        return false;
      });
    });
    // display values in js console
    console.log(array);
    // counter for number of books
    $('#numOfBooks').text(array.length);
    // clears input field
    // $('#input').prop("selected", false);
  });

  // on click submit values
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    // grabs user's input
    var $input = $('#input').val();
    // stores in the array and sorts from lowest to highest
    array.push(parseInt($input));
    array.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b
    });
    // displays user's inputs
    $('#output').text(array.join(", "));
    // display values in js console
    console.log(array);
    // counter for number of books
    $('#numOfBooks').text(array.length);
    // clears input field
    // $('#input').prop("selected", false);
  });
  // reset
  $("#resetButton").on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header"> Sort Your Books </h1>
<form id="wrapper">
  <span> Enter Book Numbers: </span> <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter a Number...">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Enter">
</form>

<div class="flex_NumOfBooks">
  <h2 id="header_NumOfBooks"> Number of Books: </h2>
  <div id="numOfBooks"> </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper1">
  <h2 id="header-books"> Book Numbers: </h2>
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>

<button id="resetButton"> Reset </button>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does clearing the input after you've entered it have to do with the number of digits you can enter?

Comment: You shouldn't bind an event handler inside another event handler.

Comment: Basically, the user would enter in numbers and I would like for it to have it cleared each time the user pressed "entered" or pressed the button. I found that $('#input').val(' '); does exactly what I want; however, it doesn't allow me to enter two digit numbers like "23". I was wondering if there was another way. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: I don't see that in the code in the question. Post the code that's having the problem.

Comment: I'm also confused as to why you have your document.ready call, which is totally fine, and then have the shorthand `$(function() {})` call inside of it. The code you tried to clear the value with is totally valid and wouldn't have a bearing on the number of characters. But I think you have far bigger issues here.

Comment: Where id you put `$("#input").val('')`? It should be inside the `if(e.which == 13)` so it only runs when the user finishes entering the value.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Thanks for the tips! You are totally right about the `$(function() {})`. The problem I'm having is that the `$('#input').val(' ');` clears my previous entries; however, it doesn't allow a value greater than 9. So, for an example, like 10.

Comment: @Barmar That fixed my problem! Thank you sooo much! It makes so much sense why I would put that there! <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

please don't use jq. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="userGetBookID">
        <div class="inputGroup">
            <label>Input book id:</label>
            <input type="text" class="bookID" placeholder="e.g. esbn-123-abfgd">
            <input type="button" class="addBookByID" value="add">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="books">
        <div class="listGroup">
            <p class="books__list-header">list:</p>
            <div class="books__list"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="amountGroup">
            <p class="books__amount-header"> amount: </p>
            <p class="books__amount"> 0 </p>
        </div>
        <button class="listReset"> reset </button>
    </div>

    <script>
        const userInput = document.querySelector('.bookID')
        const userList = document.querySelector('.books__list')
        const userSubmit = document.querySelector('.addBookByID')
        const userReset = document.querySelector('.listReset')
        const userListAmount = document.querySelector('.books__amount')



        const getUserInput = () => userInput.value
        const getUserList = () => userList.innerText.split(', ')
        const resetUserInput = () => userInput.value = ""
        const resetUserList = () => userList.innerText = ""
        const addToUserList = (value) => getUserList()[0] == ""
            ? userList.innerText += value
            : userList.innerText += (', ' + value)

        const getUserListLength = () => getUserList()[0] == ""
            ? 0
            : getUserList().length
        const updateUserListAmount = () => userListAmount.innerText = getUserListLength()

        userSubmit.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            addToUserList(getUserInput())
            resetUserInput()
            updateUserListAmount()
            event.preventDefault()
        })

        userReset.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            resetUserList()
            updateUserListAmount()
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```